# which VBA macro to give the date when a cell is filled, but not when whatever event occurs

Tags: excel, vba, events

I have an excel file that is actually a database that I update regularly. Each time that I do an update, I want to filter the data I entered on that particular day.

So I found this macro online that is really great for my application.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim C As Range, D As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
    Set C = Range("C:C")
    Set Inte = Intersect(C, Target)
    If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In Inte
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

It gives me the cell D the date of the day when I modified the cell C. The problem is, I only want the date to appear if I really put a text in the cell C. Sometimes I just insert a line, but empty in cell C, and the macro considers it as an event. It then gives me the date in cell D, however I haven't written anything.

I guess this should be a pretty simple line to add somewhere in the macro with a `If Not IsEmpty(C.Value) Then` but I haven't been able to put it at the correct place, since it doesn't work...

Thank you in advance for any help you may procure. And have a nice weekend all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim C As Range, D As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
    Set C = Range("C:C")
    Set Inte = Intersect(C, Target)
    If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In Inte
        If Not IsEmpty(r.Value) Then  ' line added
        r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
        Else
        r.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
        End If
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you Ahmed AU! It actually works perfectly when I add a line but don't write anything in cell C.
Do you think I could even more update it to have nothing in cell D even if I began writing in cell C, but it was finally a mistake and I erased the content of cell C? Because as soon as I write something in cell C, the date appears in cell D and stays here even if I erase cell C just after.

Comment: Edited answer according to your requirement. May accept the answer if it serves your purpose.

Comment: Hi Ahmed AU, I still have another update I'd like to make to this macro that I don't succeed in. I would like, in the same worksheet, to have exactly the same code that would do the same thing but in other columns. When I write in columnO, I would like it to write the date in columnP. I've had errors with everything I've tried to combine two codes. The only thing that works is if I have two separate codes but I call the second one Worksheet_selectionChange() instead of Worksheet_Change(). However, this option makes the column P to actualise only when I leave the cell in O and I go back to it.

Comment: If i understand you correctly that you further want to add the same functionality of  Column C to to Column O also, Then change `Set C = Range("C:C")`  to  `Set C = Union(Range("C:C"), Range("O:O"))`.It will work for both Column C and O.

Comment: it was so simple! thank you! actually so simple that I thought it would be two different codes and that I could modify the second one afterwards without annoying you with more questions. I would like to have the date written in column P only when I write "reserved" in column O, and not when I write anything else. I'm sorry about that. thank you so much for your time!

Comment: may replace the line `If Not IsEmpty(r.Value) Then` with `If (Not IsEmpty(r.Value) And Not Intersect(r, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing) Or (UCase(r.Value) = "RESERVED" And Not Intersect(r, Range("O:O")) Is Nothing) Then` to Column P to add date only with word "reserved"  in column O. May omit `Ucase` if not required.

Answer (score 0):

Use SpecialCells to act on not empty cells only

And you don’t need to loop

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Inte As Range

    Set Inte = Intersect(Range("C:C"), Target)
    If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Inte.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment DisplayName. It unfortunately doesn't work, since as soon as I write womething in a C cell, it writes the date in all the cells where there was already something written, in all the columns except for A and B.